problem with RTF: velocityContext and russian symbols
problem description
There is a document template in rtf format, we replace the placeholders with other data - it works correctly. But if you insert Russian characters, the result will be :
Ñ€ÑƒÑÑÐºÐ¸Ðµ ÑÐ»Ð¾Ð²Ð°.

Only russian characters that replaced placeholders are displayed incorrectly (the rest of the russian words in the template and output are correct)
The encoding is UTF-8 everywhere. As a final result, Postman’s response contains these russian words, but if you open it in Word, for example, or LibreOffice, the inserted russian words are displayed incorrectly.
technologies used

java
springboot 3
apache poi

How to fix this problem?

Please never post images of text. They are not searchable, we cannot copy-paste... Always copy-paste the text and format it properly.
An RTF file is not a text file with lines as such. Your code can be return Files.readString(Path.of(templateFile), StandardCharsets.UTF_8); Please tell us why you're returning byte[] (as opposed to String) after doing the merge

I need return byte[] for front- its idea(task):  all jobs have to be on backend

I don't understand that, but it's a possibility that whatever is processing it is not decoding the codepoints in that array properly

yes but how can I fix it? Also I add my controller to the question

checkEncoding(templateContent) it's interesting that you show no such method in your code. There is a detectEncoding method. The one that accepts a String as a parameter, is pointless btw. The answer will always be 'variant UTF-16'

Also I changed return statement to Resourse. Result was similar

It's good we have your code, though you need to work on formatting it properly

private static String checkEncoding(String text) {
return StandardCharsets.UTF_8.displayName();
}

I'm not fully familiar with all the APIs used here. I still don't see what's actually processing that byte[]

we pass the byte array of the generated document (rtf with replaced words) to fronend, and there the document will be generated for the user

... to fronend, and there the document will be generated for the user That could only happen if there is Javascript doing the 'generation'. Otherwise, it's actually happening at the back end.

JS would be but now I have to return correct data fot it

Sorry, I don't understand that either. And I still don't really understand why you turn a string into a byte array

what I have to return for task: update rtf by replace placeholders and return to frontend data for accumulate document in rtf format

It might be a good idea to post a link to a sample template. But your description doesn't really match what's happening. afaics the transformation has already been done before it leaves the server, so you can simply receive the transformed document at the client. What's happening at the client is still mysterious

that's right, I just need to transfer the modified document to the client. The problem lies in the transmitted document: the russian words that we substituted are presented in an unreadable form, all other russian words are read normally.

Try calling this on each template parameter: public static String toRtfUnicode(String s) {return s.codePoints().mapToObj(i -> "\\uc1\\u%d".formatted(i)).collect(Collectors.joining());}

decide task by using apache poi without templete. Create document by code. Using this tutorial https://mkyong.com/java/java-read-and-write-microsoft-word-with-apache-poi/#update-document/. Maybe would be useful to someone.

Btw I tested a template with and without the code I posted using Utf-8 Russian text and it worked fine
